# Positioning textboxes and other elements

Tags: html, css, textbox

I have a page on my wesite with a game built in. I want to move my textbox so it appears to the right of the game and not under like it does by default. I wish to do this with external CSS if possible.

My HTML code:

```
<p class="overskrift">Nettside Oppgave</p>

<iframe class="zombieKillah" src="https://scratch.mit.edu/projects/391981910/embed" allowtransparency="true" width="485" height="402" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" allowfullscreen></iframe>

<!--Textbox explaining controls for the game-->
<p class="undertekst_spill1" >Kontroll: </br>Pil venstre/høyre snur deg i bestemt retning. </br>Pil opp flytter deg i retningen figuren ser. </br>Mellomrom skyter våpenet du holder i hånden. </br>1 og 2 veksler mellom våpen. </p>
```

My CSS code:

```
/*Game on "spill" page*/
.zombieKillah {
    color: lightblue;
    width: 600px;
    height: 600px;
    background-color: black;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 70px;
    top: 300px;
    text-align: center;
}
.zombieKillah {
    margin: 1 auto;
    margin-left: 1 auto;
    margin-right: 1 auto;
}

/*Textbox for "spill" page*/
.undertekst_spill1 {
    color: lightblue;
    width: 300px;
    background-color: black;
    padding: 30px;
    margin: 70px;
    top: 300px;
    text-align: left;
}

.undertekst_spill1
{
margin: 0 auto;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
}
```

For clarification these textboxes are not for input but to read the controls you have to use in-game.

Comment: Which is your textbox here ? didn't get you

Answer (score 0):

You can align the `textbox` to the top if you prefer with `align-items: flex-start;`.

---

> **Notice:** You can also change the `@media` for display it as column in smaller resolutions.

```css
/*Game on "spill" page*/
.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

@media (max-width:768px) {
  .container {
   flex-direction: column; 
  } 
}
.zombieKillah {
    color: lightblue;
    width: 600px;
    height: 600px;
    background-color: black;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 70px;
    top: 300px;
    text-align: center;
}
.zombieKillah {
    margin: 1 auto;
    margin-left: 1 auto;
    margin-right: 1 auto;
}

/*Textbox for "spill" page*/
.undertekst_spill1 {
    color: lightblue;
    width: 300px;
    background-color: black;
    padding: 30px;
    margin: 70px;
    top: 300px;
    text-align: left;
}

.undertekst_spill1
{
margin: 0 auto;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
}
```

```html
<p class="overskrift">Nettside Oppgave</p>
<div class="container">
<iframe class="zombieKillah" src="https://scratch.mit.edu/projects/391981910/embed" allowtransparency="true" width="485" height="402" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" allowfullscreen></iframe>

<!--Textbox explaining controls for the game-->
<p class="undertekst_spill1" >Kontroll: </br>Pil venstre/høyre snur deg i bestemt retning. </br>Pil opp flytter deg i retningen figuren ser. </br>Mellomrom skyter våpenet du holder i hånden. </br>1 og 2 veksler mellom våpen. </p>
</div>
```